# Bug CSS Chrome, IE e Firefox

Tags: css3

Não estou conseguindo compreender um Bug entre os navegadores.

Veja essa imagem de como está ficando no Chrome e IE e como fica no Firefox
!(https://ibb.co/mv5DRS)

```
// CSS (Less)
 div{
    p{
        position: relative;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 0 0 10px;
        left: 10%;
        top: 18vw;
        width: 90%;

        span{
            padding: 0.2% 4%;
            color: #000;
            background-color: #193944;
            font-size: 320%;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            }
    }
```

}

Fiz aqui pra demonstrar e funcionou perfeito. Mas no meu CSS da o erro da imagem. Imagino que seja algo relacionado ao Reset do CSS.

```css
div{
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #2222;
  position: relative;
  }
  div p{
        position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 0 10px;
  left: 10%;
  top: 18vw;
  width: 90%;
  }
  div p span{
     padding: 0.2% 4%;
     color: #fff;
  background-color: #193944;
  font-size: 220%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <p><span>Texto</span></p>
  <p><span>Mais Texto Aqui</span></p>
  <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: vc já tentou remover seu reset para ver o que acontece?

Comment: Explique melhor o que você quer dizer com erro de imagem, em seu exemplo não há nenhuma e a apresentação está exatamente igual no chrome e no firefox.

Comment: Tente limpar o cache do navegador.

Comment: [h3nr1ke], o meu Resete é bem simples 5 linhas no máximo. Retirei... dá no mesmo. 

[Leandro Angelo], não tem erro de imagem é de renderização dos navegadores, a imagem coloco como fica a renderização no Chrome, IE e Firefox. Na simulação que eu fiz usando um código semelhante aqui pra demonstrar está funcionando correto, mas no meu site não.

[dvd], faço isso o tempo todo.

Comment: O que vc colocou aqui na demonstração funciona no Firefox normal?

Comment: Quero dizer, vc abrindo aqui o site no Firefox se funcional normal. Ou seja, apenas no seu site que tah bixado.

Comment: Se seu site estiver online e puder colocar o link aqui pra gente dar uma olhada.